# Flutter: Exception: Android toolchain - develop for Android devices exceeded maximum allowed duration of 0:10:00.000000

Tags: flutter, android-studio

`flutter doctor` gives the following error:

```
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[☠] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (the doctor check crashed) ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues. ✗ Exception: Android toolchain - develop for Android devices exceeded maximum allowed duration of 0:10:00.000000
```

I have installed the latest Android SDK Command-line Tools in Android Studio

I have tried setting the location of SDK via flutter config --android-sdk /Users/mooreihu/Library/Android/sdk

I have tried running flutter doctor --android-licenses, and it hangs indefinitely. I never reached a timeout or anything like that.

I am not sure what else to try, haven't found much on this specific issue online. Thank you for any help!

Here is my complete flutter doctor -v output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.1, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.3.1 on channel stable at /Users/mooreihu/Downloads/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4f9d92fbbd (8 days ago), 2022-09-06 17:54:53 -0700
    • Engine revision 3efdf03e73
    • Dart version 2.18.0
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[☠] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please
      let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ Exception: Android toolchain - develop for Android devices exceeded maximum allowed duration of
      0:10:00.000000
    • 

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A309
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/mooreihu/Library/Application
      Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/221.5921.22/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 105.0.5195.102

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to used Java 8 instead of Java 11

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Java 8 instead of your actual version of Java and reboot the computer!!