# Connected device (the doctor check crashed) (flutter problem)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, emulation

Connected device (the doctor check crashed)
X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
X Exception: Connected device exceeded maximum allowed duration of 0:04:30.000000

please I want solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721268/flutter-exception-android-toolchain-develop-for-android-devices-exceeded-max